# how to set a property value according to profile

Tags: maven

I'm new to maven and i got this issue when sometimes when i run maven i want to have a property with 1 value and sometimes the other.
I tried to do the following but still something is missing:

```
 <profiles>
<profile>
    <id>production</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>com.sencha.cmd.dir</name>
            <value>
                ${env.SENCHA_PATH}\senchaCmd-${com.sencha.cmd.version}\Sencha\Cmd\${com.sencha.cmd.version}
            </value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
</profiles>

<properties>
 <com.sencha.cmd.dir> ${env.SENCHA_PATH}\senchaCmd- ${com.sencha.cmd.version}\Sencha\Cmd\${com.sencha.cmd.version}</com.sencha.cmd.dir>
```

my question is how to replace the value of the property com.sencha.cmd.dir according to the availability of the profile?

Hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really simple

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
   <id>profile 1</id>
   <activation>
     ...
   </activation>
   <properties>
     <my.property> xxx </my.property>
   </properties>
 </profile>
 <profile>
   <id>profile 2</id>
   <activation>
     ...
   </activation>
   <properties>
     <my.property> yyy </my.property>
   </properties>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

and then you can use your my.properties outside, even in an other one properties

```
<properties>
 <my.next.property> abc ${my.property} def </my.next.property>
</properties>
```

Comment: Pieret. i guess i didn't explain what i want to do. so according to your example is it possible to do something like:<properties>
 <my.next.property>  ${my.property} OR </my.next.property>
</properties> which means that in case i don't have my.property defined can i use my.next.property?

Comment: If ${my.property} can not exist in differents profiles, just defined it with a blank. I think it's a clear way.